# Why do I get #N/A (#N/B) as the outcome of an Exact Online formula in Excel with Invantive Control?

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

In my Excel sheets there are cell formulas that don't show any values, but instead give "#N/A" ("#N/B").

For example, the formula:

```
=I_EOL_GL_ACT_DESCRIPTION("868056"; "4000")
```

does not return "Salaries" from Exact Online, but #N/A (in Dutch #N/B).

Other formulas such as `=SUM(...)` work fine.

Why does the Invantive Control plugin for Excel return "#N/A"?

Answer (score 2):

When you expect your cells to have a value, but instead it states "#N/A" / "#N/B", you can check for the following:

> **1.** You are not yet connected to Exact Online within Excel, you can connect to Exact Online here:

[image: Connect with Exact Online]

> **2.** In order to see the result of your model, the model needs to be enabled, you can do that like so:

[image: Enable your model]

> **3.** The cells aren't formatted for the expected value. This happens for example when the value is a number, but the cell is formatted as text, you can right-click the cell and choose 'Format Cells', then you can select the right formatting as following:

[image: Format the cell properly]